# How to display username on the header of every page?

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I am stuck with a problem. I would like to display "Welcome Username" on the header of every page especially ".html" pages. Since it is an html page, I don't think I can use PHP. Also, I want it to work without javascript.

So in overview:
 - Display username in header of html page (.html)
 - No javascript
 - Retrieve username in cookies

It is used on the website japan-guide.com. However, I am confused on how they do it. It seems like that they use PHP. However, it is an .html page and links are all to .html pages. So there is seems to be no .php page inbetween.

I tried searching it online, but can't find it. 
Thanks for your help.

---

I was wondering. Can I use an iframe in the html that displays the php code for "Welcome Username". Would that work? Our would it be better to change all my html files into php and do some modifying later.

Comment: You can't have dynamic content in a static language.

Comment: Don't trust to what you see in url. Even if it ends in `.html` - it doesn't mean it's a plain text html. The same true for any other "extensions"

Comment: You can't see the source code in your browser. You only see the html output.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar: apache is not the only webserver in the world. And even with apache you could do that without even touching `.htaccess`

Comment: use layouts and have the user name displayed in the header part.

Comment: @zerkms I only worked with Apache most of time. Can you give me link for doing this without touching `.htaccess`.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar: sure - do it in `httpd.conf` :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I was wondering. Can I use an iframe in the html that displays the php code for "Welcome Username". Would that work? Our would it be better to change all my html files into php and do some modifying later.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms).
You cannot entirely trust a site with all of its page ends in `html`.
Dynamic content processor such as PHP can be modified (using web server setting) to allows you to execute any file extension, including `html`.